# Linear transformation of a function vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, change-of-basis

I'm having a bit of trouble solving a homework problem. I've given the specific problem below, but general answers are 100% welcome:

> Consider the following three bases for a vector space , which is a subspace of $C^\infty(-\infty,\infty):$
> $$B_1 = \{ 1, e^x, e^{2x}\}$$
> $$B_2 = \{ 1, 1+e^{2x}, e^x -e^{2x}\}$$
> $$B_3 = \{ 1+e^x, 1+e^{2x}, 1+e^x+e^{2x}\}$$
>
> Obtain the following transition matrices:
> $$P_{B_1 \to B_2}, P_{B_2 \to B_1}, P_{B_2 \to B_3}$$

I've read about change of basis and done problems for questions like this in finite vector spaces ($\mathbb{R}^n$ and $M_{nm}$, etc). But the way we're given to solve equations involves utilizing the inverse of the basis, which I'm not certain on calculating. At first observation, I can see that I could pull out $\vec{x} = \{1,e^x,e^{2x}\}$ in order to at least simplify what I'm looking at:

$$B_1 = A_1\vec{x} = \begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1\\e^x\\e^{2x} \end{bmatrix}$$
$$B_2 = A_2\vec{x} = \begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0\\1&0&1\\0&1&-1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1\\e^x\\e^{2x} \end{bmatrix}$$
$$B_3 = A_3\vec{x} = \begin{bmatrix} 1&1&0\\1&0&1\\1&1&1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1\\e^x\\e^{2x} \end{bmatrix}$$

This allows me to view each basis at least in the sense of something which isn't one dimensional. I know from my text that a transition vector can be expressed as $P_{A \to B} = [B]^{-1}[A]$ (where A and B are bases), as well as:

$$AA^{-1} = I\\
IA = A\\
(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1}A^{-1}\\
[B] = [\vec{u}_1| \vec{u}_2| ...| \vec{u}_n]\\
A\vec{x}=\vec{b}\\
\vec{x}=A^{-1}\vec{b}$$

With the final two holding true if A is invertible. I've expressed all the bases in the form $\vec{b} = A\vec{x}$, so following the above logic (since every A from our bases is invertible), I believe the following should hold true:
$$
P_{B_1 \to B_2} = B_2^{-1}B_1\\
... = (A_2\vec{x})^{-1}(A_1\vec{x})\\
... = (\vec{x})^{-1}A_2^{-1}A_1\vec{x}\\
\vec{x}P_{B_1 \to B_2} = A_2^{-1}A_1\vec{x}$$

However, I'm having trouble getting rid of or simplifying that $\vec{x}$ around. I'm also not certain if it's even appropriate to denote a non-square $\vec{x}^{-1}$. But I feel like there must be a way to simplify $(\vec{x})^{-1}M\vec{x} \to M$.

Failing that, I also tried:

$$rank(B_{1...3}) = 3\\
\therefore dim(V) = 3\\
\therefore \forall \vec{v} \in V, \vec{v} \in \mathbb{R}^3$$

So by this, I believe we can determine that while $C^\infty$ is an infinite-dimensional vector space, $V$ is actually a 3-dimensional subspace described by our bases.

But I suppose this also leaves me a littlle confused, as it would mean e.g. $1 + e^x$ (from $B_{3,1}$) is actually a third-dimensional vector, which is what lead me to breaking down the bases given based on the variable inputs over addition.

In short:

- Is my approach flawed or incorrect? If so, how?
- I'm a bit short on terminology since I'm learning, is there a name for what I did in that first step?
- Most importantly: How do I generate the transition vector for this subspace?

Comment: Your first set of assertions that 
$$B_1 = A_1\vec{x} = \begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1\\e^x\\e^{2x} \end{bmatrix}$$
etc, are not correct. Here you're saying that the basis $B_1$ is the $3$-dimensional *vector* $(1, e^{x}, e^{2x})$, but a basis is not a vector it is a **set** of vectors, in this case, the set of the $1$-dimensional vectors $\{1, e^x, e^{2x}\}$. You can't manipulate a basis in the same way you manipulate a vector or a matrix.

Comment: @SeraPhim okay, so the initial premise was wrong. Though isn't $A_1\vec{x}$ still a $3x1$ vector ($3x3 * 3x1$)? I'm aware a basis is a set of vectors (see the end paragraph), which is why it's confusing to me to assert that $\{1, e^x, e^{2x}\}$ is a basis, as in order to calculate the transition vector with our given equations I would need to calculate $[B]^{-1}$. But as far as I'm aware, you can't inverse a non-square matrix / vector. Plus in order for $[B]^{-1}(\vec{v})_B = \vec{v}$ to hold for an $m x 1$ matrix $\vec{v}$, I'd assume $B$ would have to be an $m x m$ matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Let us take
$$b_1=1$$
$$b_2=e^x$$
$$b_3=e^{2x}$$
and
$$c_1=1$$
$$c_2=1+e^{2x}$$
$$c_3=e^x-e^{2x}$$
which translate in
$$c_1=b_1$$
$$c_2=b_1+b_3$$
$$c_3=b_2-b_3$$
the second has associated matrix
$C=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}1&0&0\\1&0&1\\0&1&-1\end{array}\right]$.

But also if
$$d_1=1+e^x$$
$$d_2=1+e^{2x}$$
$$d_3=1+e^x+e^{2x}$$
then
$$d_1=b_1+b_2$$
$$d_2=b_1+b_3$$
$$d_3=b_1+b_2+b_3$$
with associated matrix
$D=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}1&1&1\\1&0&1\\0&1&1\end{array}\right]$.

So if you want to see how to express $d_1,d_2,d_3$ in terms of the $c_1,c_2,c_3$ you ought to solve and get
$$b_1=c_1$$
$$b_2=-c_1+c_2+c_3$$
$$b_3=-c_1+c_2$$
that has associated matrix
$C^{-1}=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}1&-1&-1\\0&1&1\\0&1&0\end{array}\right]$.

And subbing we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
d_1&=&c_1+(-c_1+c_2+c_3)=c_2+c_3\\
d_2&=&c_1+(-c_1+c_2)=c_2\\
d_3&=&c_1+(-c_1+c_2+c_3)+(-c_1+c_2)=-c_1+2c_2+c_3
\end{eqnarray*}
that has  associated matrix
$A=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}0&0&-1\\1&1&2\\1&0&1\end{array}\right]$.

This, is the multiplication
$$C^{-1}D=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}1&-1&-1\\0&1&1\\0&1&0\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}1&1&1\\1&0&1\\0&1&1\end{array}\right].
$$